# An alternative single word for "He/She" and "his/her"?

Tags: word-request, personal-pronouns, singular-they

In the following sentence ( taking it as an example )

> Everyone applying for scholarship has to fill the form. He/She must also provide his/her result card with his/her form.

I am wondering, can I possibly use some word instead of "He/She" and "his/her" which will provide the same meaning? ( I need a word if possible. I know that changing the structure of sentence can be done to avoid using he/she and his/her )

Comment: Would "*Applicants* must also provide *their* result cards with *their* forms" be okay?

Comment: @Drossel yes, it definitely would be okay... But as I said, I am basically looking for an alternative word for he/she and his/her. 
Just took the above sentence as an example.

Comment: You could also use the *singular they*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the gender hasn't been identified, "they/their/them" must be applied instead of his/her him/her, such as your example, see:

> Everyone applying for scholarship has to fill the form. He/She must also provide his/her result card with his/her form.

-

> Everyone applying for scholarship has to fill the form. **They** must also provide **their** result card with **their** form.

As "***Everyone***" is a non-identified gender, but it is considered singular, it explains the usage of "has", but if you answer goes along you will probably face the need of using non-identified genders, that's where "They/them/their" fit.

But, if you are telling a story, such as someone looking at your girlfriend or boyfriend, and you know who you were talking about, you could say: *The last week's party was awesome, but there were some guys looking at my friend, **she** got really mad and left the party*

"***friend***" is a non-identified gender, but it can easily be identified after you increased the "*she*", which implies to say that your friend was female.